# find title of empty Div in Table Row - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

There is a Div class & title which changes in this Table Row often. I need to catch the div when it reads something specific.

code looks like this:

```
<tr class="this_row">
<td class="something"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
    <div class="i_need_this" title="or This"></div>
</td>
</td></td>
<td class="blah"></td>
```

etc.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'this_row')//div[contains(@class, 'i_need_this')]")).getText().contains("This text matches exactly within td class=blah from above"))
```

Which does not work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a job for Explicit Waits with [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and Expected Conditions:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement td = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.cssSelector("tr.this_row td.blah"), "This text matches exactly within td class=blah from above"));
```

Here, we are waiting *up to* 10 seconds for `This text matches exactly within td class=blah from above` text to appear inside the `td` element with class `blah` inside the `tr` element with class `this_row`.

Or, we can also wait for the specific `div` element *to become present*:

```
WebElement div = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr.this_row > td > div")));
System.out.println(div.getAttribute("title"));
```

Comment: I did just have an instance where "or this" was in "tr.this_row > td > div" but still reported Title not found ... Is there a way to be more broad? Maybe multiple instances of "or this" found within "tr.this_row > td > div" confused it? Does it find the top most instance only? thanks!

Comment: How do I find bottom most instance of tr.this_row ? Thanks!!

Comment: @Zodzie try `tr.this_row:last-of-type > td > div` css selector

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr.this_row > td > div")).getAttribute("title").contains("or This")){testFollows();}
    else {System.out.print("title not found \n");}
}
    public static void testFollows() throws InterruptedException {
        if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr.this_row")).getText().contains("This text matches exactly within td class=blah from above"))
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found Target");} 
        else {System.out.print("found nothing2 \n");}
    }
```

Could not have done it without answer from alecxe.

THANKS!